# Google maps api en mi web react no se mueve

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-api

Voy a utilizar @vis.gl/react-google-maps": "^0.7.1, y no puedo mover mi mapa, siempre vuelve al centro. No tengo ni idea de cómo solucionarlo. Por favor, ayúdenme

```
import {
  APIProvider,
  Map
} from "@vis.gl/react-google-maps";
import './App.css';
import Barra from "./componentes/Barra";
import Informacion from "./componentes/Informacion";

function App() {
  const defaultPosition = { lat: 39.575387, lng: 2.653255 };
  
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Barra />
        <div className="container">
          <Informacion className="controls" />
          <APIProvider apiKey="MY_KEY">
            <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
              <Map zoom={15}  center={defaultPosition} mapId={"d8135e8ab27ce954"}>
              </Map>
            </div>
          </APIProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Quiero usar el mapa para colocar algunos AdvancedMarker en él. El usuario debería poder moverse libremente para verlo.

Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!